# File transfer in Azure Integration Services

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement where I need to transfer file (20-150 MB) between two systems. For this requirement , is it better to use Durable function instead of Azure data factory (ADF). As per my understanding , ADF execution will costlier as compared to durable functions. Note : durable function  trigger is eventGrid trigger. Any suggestion will be helpful. File transfer will be simple pass through, no transformation is involved.

Also, for my requirement even simple azure function will work right instead of durable function? There is no need of function orchestration as file is not processed in batch. Since, file will be processed based on event trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my experience, I would like to recommend using Azure functions over ADF is a good idea because of the following reasons:

1. Azure Data Factory is too expensive. ADF costs way more than azure functions.
2. Custom Logic: ADF is not built to perform cleansing logics or any custom code. Its primary goal is for data integration from external systems using its vast connector pool
3. Latency: ADF has much higher latency due to the large overhead of its job framework

Durable function is just related to the maximum execution time of a single call. For "out of the box" functions, that timeout is 10min, for durable functions this limitation gets removed. In this case, where you simply need to copy the data, there might be timeout issue and therefore you can consider the Durable function. Otherwise, simple function should also work fine. Moreover, Durable functions and normal functions share the same billing pattern.

For more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp